# SegFault involving passing and index of an array to a floating point variable after an iteration for 10 iterations

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, segmentation-fault

All of this is contained in the function getTravelCO2.

int getTravelCO2(float tripCO2s[MAX_NUM_TRIPS], int tripTypes[MAX_NUM_TRIPS], char
tripNames[MAX_NUM_TRIPS][MAX_TRIP_NAME_LEN], float *totalTripCO2, float
CO2FactorBus, float CO2FactorTain, float CO2FactorPlane);

- Description: This function serves the same purpose as the travel section in A1. There
  are two changes, we can have up to 10 trips instead of 3, and the user will enter a trip
  name in addition to type and distance.
- Parameter(s):
- tripCO2s: this array stores the CO2 emissions (in KG) for each of the trips the
  user entered.
- tripTypes: this array stores the input the user entered while selecting the type of
  trip (ie. 1 for bus, 2 for train, 3 for aeroplane, 4 for none) for each of the trips the
  user entered.
- tripNames: this array stores the strings the user enters for the names of the trips.
  Use getTripName function to retrieve the string.
- totalTripCO2: this pass by reference value should be set to the total CO2 for all
  trips.
- CO2FactorBus: the carbon factor for busses per km.
- CO2FactorTain: the carbon factor for trains per km.
- CO2FactorPlane: the carbon factor for aeroplanes per km.
- Text Output: The function starts with a message “The following section will…” see A1 for
  full text. This function prompts the user for input three times per trip, first for the type of
  trip (using the same menu options as A1), then for a string (using the getTripName
  function) representing the name of the trip: “Where/What was this trip? Only enter 10 or
  less characters: ", and finally for the distance of the trip. This is repeated until the user
  selects option 4 “None” or 10 trips have been entered. Before returning the function ends
  with “You have completed the travel section.”
- Return: the number of trips (0 - 10)
- Notes: use the getIntInput function for the menu selection, getFloatInput for the number
  of km, and the getTripName for the trip name.

under each of the cases I got a segfault which I thought was because I was accessing an index of the array which I wasn't allowed to.

I tried fixing this by using tripCO2s[MAX_NUM_TRIPS -1] although that too gives me a segfault.

when I ran the iteration below, I prompted for case 1 and the segfault occurs a couple lines below in the updating for pointer *totalTripCO2

```
int getTravelCO2(float tripCO2s[MAX_NUM_TRIPS], int tripTypes[MAX_NUM_TRIPS], char tripNames[MAX_NUM_TRIPS][MAX_TRIP_NAME_LEN], float *totalTripCO2, float CO2FactorBus, float CO2FactorTrain, float CO2FactorPlane)
{

    printf("\nThe following section will ask you about your travel in the past year.\nyou will be able to enter up to 10 trips.\n ");

    int TravelLoop = 1;
    while (TravelLoop <= MAX_NUM_TRIPS)
    {

        printf("\nWhat form of travel did you use for trip %d in the past year?\n", TravelLoop++);
        printf("1) Bus\n");
        printf("2) Train\n");
        printf("3) Aeroplane\n");
        printf("4) None\n");

        tripTypes[MAX_NUM_TRIPS] = getIntInput("Enter Choice (1-4): ", 1, 4);
        if (tripTypes[MAX_NUM_TRIPS] == 4)
        {
            break;
        }

        getTripName("\nWhere/What was this trip? Only Enter 10 or less characters: ", tripNames[MAX_TRIP_NAME_LEN]);

        switch (tripTypes[MAX_NUM_TRIPS])
        {

        case 1:
            tripCO2s[MAX_NUM_TRIPS] = getFloatInput("\nEnter the total km you traveled by bus in the trip: ");
            *totalTripCO2 = tripCO2s[MAX_NUM_TRIPS - 1] * CO2FactorBus;

            break;

        case 2:
            tripCO2s[MAX_NUM_TRIPS] = getFloatInput("\nEnter the total km you travelled by train in one trip: ");
            *totalTripCO2 = tripCO2s[MAX_NUM_TRIPS-1] * CO2FactorTrain;

            break;

        case 3:
            tripCO2s[MAX_NUM_TRIPS] = getFloatInput("\nEnter the total km you travelled by areoplane in one trip:  ");

            *totalTripCO2 = tripCO2s[MAX_NUM_TRIPS-1] * CO2FactorPlane;

            break;

        default:
            tripCO2s[MAX_NUM_TRIPS] = 0;
            totalTripCO2;
            break;
        }

        *totalTripCO2 += tripCO2s[MAX_NUM_TRIPS - 1];
        tripTypes[MAX_NUM_TRIPS - 1]++;
    }
    printf("\nYou have completed the travel section\n");
    return 0; // supposed to return the number of trips however many
}
```

Comment: If the array `tripTypes` have `MAX_NUM_TRIPS` elements, then the value `MAX_NUM_TRIPS` is out of bounds. Remember that array indexes go from `0` to the size minus one. So for `tripTypes` the indexes are from `0` to `MAX_NUM_TRIPS - 1`. You do this mistake at a lot of places. What are you really trying to do? What are the purposes of the arrays?

Comment: Take for example `tripTypes[MAX_NUM_TRIPS] = getIntInput("Enter Choice (1-4): ", 1, 4)`... What are you really trying to do here? Why are you assigning the result to what seems to be a totally unrelated array element? Why not `int choice = getIntInput("Enter Choice (1-4): ", 1, 4)` instead?

Comment: On a totally different and unrelated note, unless you have very specific requirements or limitations, you shouldn't really use the type `float` for floating point numbers. Use `double`.

Comment: Instead of using `MAX_NUM_TRIPS - 1` as an array index, shouldn't you be using `TravelLoop - 1`?  You only use `TravelLoop` to control the loop, and for the prompt (where it is a *very* bad idea to use `TravelLoop++`). Also, get used to working with zero-based array indexing and don't try to force C to work with the idea of 1-based.

Comment: thank you for your replies but I dont know how to reply to yall I can only comment